# Need help making onPrepare use global variables in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, automated-tests, protractor, configuration-files, jasmine2.0

Every part of this is working except it's just dumping the initial junitresults.xml into the base folder and ignoring the code to put it into the reportPath folder.

The onComplete function is having no trouble accessing the global variables to use in its node_module. (I have to artificially have a test junitresults.xml file planted in the reportPath folder for it to work with though, because onPrepare isn't putting one there).

It seems like the function in onPrepare is totally ignoring the global variables set up inside the same onPrepare. How can I get it to access those? I even tried making a separate not-global variable for it to access and it is ignoring that too. Help please! Thanks!

```
...

    multiCapabilities: [
    { browserName: 'firefox' },
    { browserName: 'chrome' }
    ],

onPrepare: function() {

    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();   
    capsPromise.then(function(caps) {
        global.browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.replace(/ /g,"-");
        global.browserVersion = caps.caps_.version; 
        // browserName = global.browserName; // was just testing if not-global would work
        global.reportPath = 'c:/QA/test-results/' + global.browserName + '/';
    });

    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        consolidateAll: true,
        savePath: global.reportPath,
        filePrefix: 'junitresults'
    }));

    return global.browserName, global.browserVersion, global.reportPath;

},


onComplete: function() {

  var HTMLReport = require('jasmine-xml2html-converter');

  // Call custom report for html output
  testConfig = {
    reportTitle: 'Test Execution Report',
    outputPath: reportPath,
    seleniumServer: 'default',
    applicationUrl: browser.baseUrl,
    testBrowser: global.browserName + ' v.' + global.browserVersion
  };
  new HTMLReport().from(reportPath + 'junitresults.xml', testConfig);

  console.log("... aaaannnnd... done.");

},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the jasmine reporter initialization into `getCapabilities` promise resolution callback:

```
onPrepare: function() {
    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();   
    capsPromise.then(function(caps) {
        var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.replace(/ /g,"-");
        var browserVersion = caps.caps_.version; 
        var reportPath = 'c:/QA/test-results/' + browserName + '/';

        var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            consolidateAll: true,
            savePath: reportPath,
            filePrefix: 'junitresults'
        }));
    });
},
```

Also, instead of `global`, you may set properties on a globally available `browser` object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Moving the reporter initialization into `getCapabilities` had the result of successfully filing the xml files away in the appropriate directories, but it had the added unfortunate effect of changing the title of all of my test specs to "focused spec" so I can't tell which test is which anymore, and also cutting out some of my test steps out of the results entirely. :(

Comment: Also @alecxe what does setting up properties on a globally available `browser` object mean? Just changing the `global.` to `browser.` or is there more to it than that? I'm learning as I go.

Comment: @Defpotec2020 yup, change `global.` to `browser.` and every time you access a variable, use `browser.variable`.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. I am going to mark your answer as Accepted because it's mostly working, but I'm not quite there yet. When I group things like you suggested, my tests still just say "focused spec" at the top and not the title of my test like it gives me if I have things ungrouped.